# Repeating relative pronouns

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Is it generally permissible to repeat relative pronouns regardless of the type of pronoun and regardless of the relative clause being restrictive or not? What I mean by that can be seen in the following trivial example:

The house which is large and (which) is painted green.

I know that in this case one would not repeat "which", but there might be situations where doing so is recommended, especially if the relative clause is long and contains an "and".

Comment: I reserve the repetition for long sentences that would lose the reader otherwise. The reader is priority #1.

Comment: English is spoken, and in English such repetition is choreographed with the intonation, like commas. If you think of every relative clause as being headed by a relative pronoun, the question is not when to repeat them, but when to drop them. The answer is whenever they're obvious, which usually means there'd be no intonation change, no comma, and the next parallel clause (they should be as similar in structure as possible) would go right on ahead without any other introduction. That's for short connected ideas; if you're changing structure or meaning, start a new relative clause.

Comment: Thank you both! If I were to have a non-restrictive clause similar to the one above (the house, which is large and which is painted green, is over there), I would never ever enclose the second relative clause/part in separate commas, right? So this „the house, which is large and which is painted green, is over there“ is grammatical and thus correct, isn’t it?

Comment: A relative pronoun has to be related to something. This: "The house which is large and (which) is painted green". is not a meaningful utterance. This would be: The house which is large and which is painted green is pretty ugly.  **That might be heard but ain't great for writing**. The large, green house is pretty ugly.

Answer (score -1):

In that case, there is no need of repeating *which* and *is*.

Comment: This would be improved with an explanation of why.